# Extracting the location of a specific colour in an image in Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I would like to ask a question related to the color detection in an image in Python 3.9. I would like to detect black color at the specific x axis in the image and extract the location of the black area in the image. Could you help me how to extract the location of the black area in an image?

I can load the image and visualize it by the following code.

```
from PIL import Image
im =Image.open('c97dae05fd9244d4d10305b8066246psXmnlRxU59D0kJ0-0.jpeg')
im.show()
import numpy
imarray = numpy.array(im)
print(imarray)
Image.fromarray(imarray)
```

Comment: Well you could loop through the x axis and get the RGB values and checking for black and saving to a list the index or something like that. Not sure what you intend with this so I can help much for now.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know How can I get RGB values?

Comment: Well each point in the array should be different array with the RGB values. Its called a 2D array

Comment: Give me a sec ill write you a proper answer. Just recreating this scenario in my pc

Answer (score 1):

Some background context before I give you a solution.
Images are 3D arrays meaning the index 1 for example will be 2 arrays deep so something like this: `[[[]]]`.

For example using numpy you can check the shape of such array using `imarray.shape` which should return something like `(3888, 5184, 3)`. With this information you can see that there are 3888 arrays that contain 5184 arrays that contain 3 values.

You can maybe see a pattern occur. RGB is red, green, blue (3 values) and the third array is 3 values long which is where you will find your RGB values.

Lets take a image I had in my computer as example. I loaded it using pillow and made it into a numpy array, just like you did.

```
from Pill import Image
import numpy
im = Image.open('G0626494.jpg')
imarray = numpy.array(im)
```

Lets now print `imarray`:

This should print some columns and rows and RGB values, normally some from the beginning, middle and end.

```
array([[[ 66, 143, 185],
        [ 64, 141, 183],
        [ 60, 137, 179],
        ...,
        [ 58,  96,  75],
        [ 56,  94,  73],
        [ 57,  95,  74]],

       [[ 65, 142, 184],
        [ 63, 140, 182],
        [ 60, 137, 179],
        ...,
        [ 57,  95,  74],
        [ 56,  94,  73],
        [ 57,  95,  74]],

       [[ 63, 140, 182],
        [ 62, 139, 181],
        [ 59, 136, 178],
        ...,
        [ 57,  95,  74],
        [ 57,  95,  74],
        [ 58,  96,  75]],

       ...,

       [[ 80, 167, 195],
        [ 80, 167, 195],
        [ 82, 167, 196],
        ...,
        [130, 190, 162],
        [129, 189, 161],
        [129, 189, 161]],

       [[ 82, 169, 197],
        [ 81, 168, 196],
        [ 83, 168, 197],
        ...,
        [128, 188, 160],
        [128, 188, 160],
        [128, 188, 160]],

       [[ 82, 169, 197],
        [ 81, 168, 196],
        [ 83, 168, 197],
        ...,
        [127, 187, 159],
        [127, 187, 159],
        [127, 187, 159]]], dtype=uint8)
```

As you can see those 3 values on the 3rd array are the RGB values of the image. How do you get them?

Lets take the first pixel as example. If you know basic array manipulation in python you probably will know this but since we know the shape is 3 this means the first pixel will be under `imarray[0][0]`.

If we print this value we indeed get the RGB of the first pixel:

```
array([ 66, 143, 185], dtype=uint8)
```

Now how do you cycle through them. I challenge you to try this based on the past knowledge or try along this tutorial.

So if we have 2 arrays to get the RGB of the first pixel we need 2 loops right? So we can do it like this:

```
for row in imarray:
    for column in row:
        print(column)
```

You will now be able to see a bunch of RGB values get printed.

So lets check for black pixels now. We know black is `0, 0, 0` so we can check if any pixel is `0, 0, 0` and print it.

```
for row in imarray:
    for column in row:
        if column[0] == 0 and column[1] == 0 and column[2] == 0:
            print(column)
```

You can also check for colors next to black but not `0, 0, 0` if you check if the column values are all the same but less then 50 for example.